# I'm trying to create multiple radio buttons and I want to make sure Only one option can be picked

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm trying to create multiple radio buttons and I want to make sure only one option can be picked.

I don't know how to go about it I've forgotten the attribute used for it.

Comment: Give the set of radio buttons the same name attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Answer (score 1):

Add "name" attribute and keep the name same for all the radio buttons.

for example,

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="value1"> Value 1
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="value2"> Value 2
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="value3"> Value 3
```

Comment: Thanks, I shouldn't be forgetting these things.